# Android Retrofit - How to parse Github Emojis API

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

Please check this api: https://api.github.com/emojis

This is part of the response:

```
{
  "+1": "https://github.githubassets.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f44d.png?v8",
  "-1": "https://github.githubassets.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f44e.png?v8",
  "100": "https://github.githubassets.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f4af.png?v8",
  "1234": "https://github.githubassets.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f522.png?v8",
  "1st_place_medal": "https://github.githubassets.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f947.png?v8",
  "2nd_place_medal": "https://github.githubassets.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f948.png?v8",
  "3rd_place_medal": "https://github.githubassets.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f949.png?v8",
  "8ball": "https://github.githubassets.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f3b1.png?v8",
  "a": "https://github.githubassets.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f170.png?v8",
  "ab": "https://github.githubassets.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f18e.png?v8",
  "abacus": "https://github.githubassets.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f9ee.png?v8",
  "abc": "https://github.githubassets.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f524.png?v8",
  "abcd": "https://github.githubassets.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f521.png?v8",
}
```

I'd like to convert this response to a list of Emoji.

```
data class Emoji(
    val name: String,
    val url: String,
)
```

Note that the response is a big object and I need a list.

This is how I'm instantiating Retrofit:

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
```

How could I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't attach you Api interface but based on your descriptions you've put `List<Emoji>` in you api interface which ia going to raise a MalformedJSONException

Use a `Map<String, String>` instead and if you need a list use `responseMap.map{ Emoji(it.key, it.valie) }`

Comment: I forgot to attach my Api to the Retrofit in the question. It worked! Thanks for that!